# Limit of a Cosine Sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This seems trivial, and yet after a bit of thinking, I couldn't supply a simple proof.

Is the following true?

The series $$\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}\sum}\cos(nx)$$ is divergent for almost every $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ (or at least for a positive measure subset, though I believe a.e., or likely everywhere is correct).

Of course, as my calculus students could tell you, it would suffice to show that $$\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\cos(nx)\neq0$$ for a.e. $x$.

Heuristically, for this limit to be 0, you would have to have $nx$ essentially tracking a sequence of odd multiples of $\pi/2$ as $n$ grows, which seems implausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series does not converge for any real $x$. We show that in the "calculus" way you suggested, by showing there is no $x$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(nx)=0$.

Suppose to the contrary that  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(nx)=0$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(2nx)=0$. This is impossible, since $\cos(2nx)=2\cos^2(nx)-1$.

Comment: In your formula for $\cos((n+1)x)$, you should have $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ on the right hand side, not 1.

Comment: I had the terms reversed, corrected.

Comment: I am choosing this one because the argument is nice in its simplicity.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $\cos(nx):n\ge N$ is dense in $[-1,1]$ for any $N$ whenever $\frac x\pi$ is irrational. I think t was the name of Kronecker or Minkowski that is connected to the fact that the set
$$
\{m+nw:m,n\in\Bbb Z\}
$$
is either discrete or dense, depending on $w$ being rational or irrational

And even if this fraction $\frac x\pi$ is rational, this sequence is then periodic, and one can enumerate the cases where it is the zero sequence.

Comment: I chose the other for being very elementary, but I like this argument, it is a nice one to have in the back of my mind.